# Popular C/C++ IDE in Industry currently

Tags: c++

I wanted to know which are the top 5 IDE's in the market today for development/maintenance of C/C++ applications? I am looking for both windows and linux based IDE's. They can by open source or proprietary.

Comment: If you're looking for IDEs on multiple platforms, I recommend [Code::Blocks.](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Comment: Madhur, I suggest you go find a different development community to ask this question. The ***** here like to close every question to see their name in bright bold blue below the question. Good luck!

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of some other question. "closed for the wrong reason" © :)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is the most popular IDE.  I would say it allows large companies to make (internal) mediocre software really fast, which allows them to get back to their 'real' jobs.

As for Linux C/C++ IDEs, I'm a big fan of QT Creator myself.  It can be found from your distributions repos, or the QT website itself:  http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/

Eclipse also has a C/C++ version, I haven't tried it though.  But based on their Java version, I would bet it is fairly heavy: http://www.eclipse.org/